# Installing Microsoft Store for Business apps on Intune Managed Self-Deploying Devices

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-intune

We are having trouble with Microsoft Store for Business apps not installing, when assigned as Required to their Device group, on our Endpoint Manager (Intune) managed, Autopilot Self-Deploying, Shared PC Mode ( [EnableSharedPCMode=True](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/set-up-shared-or-guest-pc) ), configured devices. I feel like I have seen a caveat to this affect, somewhere, but have yet to find this again.

Does anyone know what might be preventing these devices from installing the Store for Business apps and, possibly, how to work around this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I have not found the official word on this, however, these are my findings.

To deploy Microsoft Store for Business Applications on devices which are Self-Deployed (rather than User-Driven Enrolled):

1. Choose the "Offline" License Type, when getting the application from the store. [image]
2. When assigning the application, change the default "User" license type to "Device" license type. [image]